# trying to remove a class when image is clicked

Tags: jquery, css

I'm try to remove a class with jquery when a image is clicked but I can seem to get it to work. 
I'm using

```
 $(this).removeClass('.title');
```

to remove this class but it's not working.

```
 .title{
   font-size: 100%;
   top: -40px;
   color: white;
   left: 0%;
   position: absolute;  
   z-index: 1;
   }
```

Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XYZZx/37/).

Comment: a simple google would of solved this http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its not

```
$(this).removeClass('.title');
```

Its

```
$(this).removeClass('title');
```

You must not use `.` when you're using `addClass` , `removeClass` and `toggleClass`. And as metioned by the other answerers, in your demo, the class `title` is not applied to `li`, but to the `div`. So you must do something like this to remove `title` :

```
$(this).find("div").removeClass('title');
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/XYZZx/39/

Comment: How could I do this for the class zoom?

Comment: for using it on class `zoom` : find the class from where you are - `$(this).find(".zoom").removeClass()`

Answer (score 1):

In your case it is not enough to do `removeClass("title")`  but you need even more:

```
$("div",this).removeClass('title');
```

Here it's working as you're expecting: http://jsfiddle.net/XYZZx/38/